# Prove $\phi$ is a homomorphism $\iff$ $h^n$=e with the givens.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a group, h $\in$ G, and n $\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. 
 Let $\phi$  : $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ $\mapsto$ G be defined by $\phi$(i)= $h^i$ for i $\in$ [0,n].
Then $\phi$ is a homomorphism $\iff$ $h^n$=e.

Proof:

($\implies$) $\phi$ a homomorphism$\implies$ $\phi$(0)=e.
So $h^n$ = $\phi$(n) = $\phi$(1+1+...+1) with n summands = $\phi$(0) = e.  $\blacksquare$

How to prove ($\Longleftarrow$) direction?

Comment: We want to show $\phi$(a+b) = $\phi(a)+\phi(b)$ given the condition. The only way I see there being any progress is using the division algorithm in some sense and reducing it to the remainder.

Comment: +1 for showing your work and asking the right question. I would prove the other direction by first showing that $h^i=h^j$ whenever $i\equiv j\pmod n$ (unless this bit was already covered when considering cyclic groups). To that end you need the assumption $h^n=e$.

Comment: So $h^{i+j}$ = $h^i*h^j$ since i + j (mod n) = i (mod n) + j (mod n) & so we thus have the homomorphism property?
How do I use the fact h^n = e?

Comment: Division algorithm.